# Many types of "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError" error in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I built so file using android-ndk-r10e and download the so file from server to /data/data/packagename.for.myapplication/myownso/armeabi-v7a/libtest.so.

before load the lib, I have checked the file's md5:

```
checkSoFileMD5();
System.load("/data/data/packagename.for.myapplication/myownso/armeabi-v7a/libtest.so");
```

It work fine in most of the time. **But**, I receive some error logs about **"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"** form the users.

pieces of them are:

```
1. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1934]:   107 missing essential tables

2. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: get_lib_extents[845]:   574 - /data/data/packagename.for.myapplication/myownso/armeabi-v7a/libtest.so is not a valid ELF object

3. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/packagename.for.myapplication/myownso/armeabi-v7a/libtest.so" is too small to be an ELF executable

4. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: empty/missing DT_HASH in "libtest.so" (built with --hash-style=gnu?)

5. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: invalid ELF file "/data/data/packagename.for.myapplication/myownso/armeabi-v7a/libtest.so" load segment[2]: p_offset (0x0) + p_filesz (0xd3ba58) ( = 0xd3ba58) past end of file (0x3a0000)
```

I can confirm that the crash devices CPU_ABI is armeabi-v7a.

Why they happen? Why these error happen on very few devices?

Comment: It can't load the library because the .so isn't a valid ELF file.  Something is wrong with your compilation if it is the right ABI.

Comment: But why only happen on few devices? And I can't reproduce it.